# Change the "Penalty Duration" value by Java code in custom NiFi processor

Tags: apache-nifi

I'm writing a custom processor in Nifi (1.23.2) and I need to update the penalty duration value based on an attribute value.

It look like it is not possible to use attribute as value, so I need to change that value by code in my processor.

So, I need to perform these steps:

1. read the value from an attribute
2. update the Penalty Duration value
3. penalize the flowfile

Is it possible?

I looked in to the NiFi code but I was not able to find any set/getPenaltyDuration methods.

Comment: you can penalize flowfile (or not). but penalty duration could be set during design time and can't be changed during execution.

Comment: To @daggett 's point, at design time you can set an annotation on the class definition for your custom processor, such as `@DefaultSettings(penaltyDuration = "5 sec")`

Comment: Unfortunately I need to set it a run-time because the penalty duration depends on the FlowFile I'm processing in that moment.